# React capacitor backbutton listener not reflecting latest state and props values

Tags: reactjs, state, listener, capacitor

I've a reactjs app including capacitor App plugin in order to handle back button actions. Plugin works as expected (alert boxes are displayed on backbutton press) however function is not reflecting current state or props values; instead it shows initial prop values when the component has loaded.
My related code as follows:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
   App.addListener("backButton", () => {
      alert(state.test)
      alert(props.test)
   })

   return () => {
     App.removeAllListeners()
   }
}, [])
```

So, how can I get latest state and props values on back button press? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add state and props to array dependencies of `useEffect`?